# Rules to extract the right path

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help to fix this code I've wrote.

```
Perc1 = ThisWorkbook.Path
Slash1 = InStrRev(Perc1, "\")
PercF = Left(Perc1, Slash1 - 1)
Slash2 = InStrRev(PercF, "\")
PercFinale = Left(PercF, Slash2) & "04-OFFERTE_CONTRATTO" & "\"
```

And the values are:

```
: Perc1 : "E:\DENNIS\01_Progetti\1_TRATTATIVE\IT.18.9462_O. Aeroporto (ROMA)\03-CALCOLO\02-XLS\Edificio E1" : Variant/String
: Slash1 : 102 : Variant/Long
: PercF : "E:\DENNIS\01_Progetti\1_TRATTATIVE\IT.18.9462_O. Aeroporto (ROMA)\03-CALCOLO\02-XLS" : Variant/String
: Slash2 : 95 : Variant/Long
: PercFinale : "E:\DENNIS\01_Progetti\1_TRATTATIVE\IT.18.9462_O. Aeroporto (ROMA)\03-CALCOLO\04-OFFERTE_CONTRATTO\" : String
```

This ends in an error because 03-CALCOLO and 04-OFFERTE_CONTRATTO are in the same folder.

I want that Percf ends always after "...\03-CALCOLO" even when I've subfolders in 02-XLS (as in this case).

Can you give me an advice please?

Thank you very much!

Dennis

Comment: Is the number parent folders above `03-CALCOLO` always consistent? If so, calculate a number of path delimiters from the left, or tokenize the string by the path delimiter and then construct a new output string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function such as:

```
Function GetRootPath(ByVal strPth As String, ByVal strTkn As String) As String
    Dim rtn As String, itm
    For Each itm In Split(strPth, "\")
        If UCase(itm) = UCase(strTkn) Then Exit For Else rtn = rtn & itm & "\"
    Next itm
    GetRootPath = rtn
End Function
```

And then construct your path using:

```
PercFinale = GetRootPath(ThisWorkbook.Path, "03-CALCOLO") & "04-OFFERTE_CONTRATTO\"
```

Comment: Thank you man, it works very well! I didn't know you were so good in VB too!

See you soon on cadtutor ;)

Comment: @DennisGrasso It's a small world it seems!